# Put names on top of matrix

Tags: tables, math-mode, matrices, bordermatrix

I am trying to produce 3 matrices on the same line. And on top of the each matrix, there is a name. I tried using `tabular` for the names and then I use `align` for the matrices. However, this creates some kind of space between the names and the matrices, which I do not want. Is there a better way to do this ? I have seen other posts but they do not seem to solve my problem. Please note that I need to use bordermatrix because I need to label the rows and columns as well.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Kay & Brian &  Edwin \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{align*}
\bordermatrix{ & I & A \cr
I &1 & 2 \cr
A & 3 & 4
} 
&
\bordermatrix{ & I & A \cr
I &5 & 6 \cr
A & 7 & 8
} 
&
\bordermatrix{ & I & A \cr
I &9 & 10 \cr
A & 11 & 12
} 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please convert your code snippets into a compilable MWE (minimum working example). The MWE should load any and all specialized packages you require as well as all custom commands you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optional argument to `\stackon` which I set to 3pt, is the spacing between the matrix and the name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-09-11]

\begin{document}
\(
\stackon[3pt]{%
\bordermatrix{ & I & A \cr
I &1 & 2 \cr
A & 3 & 4
}%
}{Kay}\quad
\stackon[3pt]{%
\bordermatrix{ & I & A \cr
I &5 & 6 \cr
A & 7 & 8
}%
}{Brian}\quad
\stackon[3pt]{%
\bordermatrix{ & I & A \cr
I &9 & 10 \cr
A & 11 & 12
} %
}{Edwin}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do I need to install a package `usestackEOL` ?

Comment: @user1769197  No, `[usestackEOL]` is an package option on the `stackengine` package.  I could actually omit it for this case, because I didn't make use of a stack that employed that feature.

Comment: But I do need to install `stackengine` package right ?

Comment: @user1769197  yes, It is at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  In the short run, you can place the .sty file in your working directory, if your installation doesn't know how to install it.  In the long run, you should figure out where LaTeX would like to place the file on your system.

Comment: thanks a lot for your great answer. Just want to know where should i place the packages in the long run. Because I dont have "texmf" folder on my system and I am using texmaker at the moment.

Comment: @user1769197 I do not use texmaker, but every tex installation has a "local installation" directory (historically with the name "localtexmf").  If texmaker has some sort of maintenance menu, it might tell you where that installation directory is.  In MikTeX, the default is, for me, C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX, but texmaker will, obviously, be a different place.

Comment: @user1769197  Perhaps this would help: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=7684

Answer (score 5):

The following example converts `\bordermatrix` to a math operator `\mathop` that allows putting a "limit" (superscript) on top of it.

Just for fun, two variants follow:

1. Curly brace over the matrix below the label.
2. Matrix label in the top left corner of the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\topbordermatrix}[2]{%
  {\mathop{\bordermatrix{#2}}\limits^{\mbox{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \topbordermatrix{Kay}{ & I & A \cr
    I &1 & 2 \cr
    A & 3 & 4
    }
    &&
    \topbordermatrix{Brian}{ & I & A \cr
    I &5 & 6 \cr
    A & 7 & 8
    }
    &&
    \topbordermatrix{Edwin}{ & I & A \cr
    I &9 & 10 \cr
    A & 11 & 12
    }
  \end{align*}

  \renewcommand*{\topbordermatrix}[2]{%
    {\overbrace{\bordermatrix{#2}}^{\mbox{#1}}}%
  }
  \begin{align*}
    \topbordermatrix{Kay}{ & I & A \cr
    I &1 & 2 \cr
    A & 3 & 4
    }
    &&
    \topbordermatrix{Brian}{ & I & A \cr
    I &5 & 6 \cr
    A & 7 & 8
    }
    &&
    \topbordermatrix{Edwin}{ & I & A \cr
    I &9 & 10 \cr
    A & 11 & 12
    }
  \end{align*}

  \renewcommand*{\topbordermatrix}[2]{%
    {\settowidth{\dimen0}{$\scriptstyle\text{#1}$}\kern\dimen0}%
    {\settowidth{\dimen0}{$A$}\kern-\dimen0}%
    \kern-\tabcolsep
    \bordermatrix{\hfill\llap{$\scriptstyle\text{#1}$}\kern-\tabcolsep #2}%
  }  
  \begin{align*}
    \topbordermatrix{Kay}{ & I & A \cr
    I &1 & 2 \cr
    A & 3 & 4
    } 
    &&
    \topbordermatrix{Brian}{ & I & A \cr
    I &5 & 6 \cr
    A & 7 & 8
    } 
    &&
    \topbordermatrix{Edwin}{ & I & A \cr
    I &9 & 10 \cr
    A & 11 & 12
    }
  \end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\NiceMatrixOptions{first-row,first-col}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Kay & Brian & Edwin \\
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  & I & A \\
I & 1 & 2 \\
A & 3 & 4
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
&
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  & I & A \\
I & 5 & 6 \\
A & 7 & 8
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
&
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  & I  & A \\
I & 9  & 10 \\
A & 11 & 12
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]